# Can't delete first post added by a user in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on social media website with laravel in which posts added by user is listed in user's profile and user can delete the post ,but everything is working perfectly except user can't delete the first post added. Why it is happening. I think the delete function from PostController is not calling when trying to delete first post.
I am giving my code

```
Route::delete('/deletepost/{id}', 'PostController@delete')->name('deletepost');
```

### PostController.php

```
public function delete($id)
{
    Post::find($id)->delete();
    if (Auth::user()->id == 1) {
        return redirect(route('admin.dashboard'))
            ->with('successMsg', 'Place Deleted Successfully');
    }else{
        return redirect(route('author.dashboard'))
            ->with('successMsg', 'Place Deleted Successfully');
    }
}
```

### code in dashboard.blade.php

```
@if(Auth::user()->posts)
    @foreach(Auth::user()->posts as $post)
    <div class="column">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <form id="delete-form-{{$post->id}}"  action="{{ route('deletepost',$post->id) }}" method="post" style="display:none">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('delete') }}
        </form>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <a href="{{ route('editpost',$post->id) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Edit</button></a>
        <button type="button"
        onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this post?')){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form-{{$post->id}}').submit();
        }else{
            event.preventDefault();
        }"
        class="btn btn-link">Delete</button>
        <div class="panel-heading">{{ $post->title }}</div>
        <a href="{{ route('showpost',$post->id) }}"><div class="panel-body"><img src="{{ asset('images/'.$post->images->first()->pictures) }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:140px" alt="Image"></div></a>
        <div class="panel-footer">{{ $post->category }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Note: delete function is working perfectly when deleting posts except first post and i am not getting any errors messages**

Comment: What error it shown on deletion?

Comment: first you can check post get or not? $post = Post::find($id);  dd($post);

Answer (score 0):

Try this on **PostController**

```
Post::destroy($id);
if(auth()->user()->id() === 1)
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->with('msg', 'deleted!');
return redirect()->route('author.dashboard')->with('msg', 'deleted!');
```

First line will delete Post based on ID. rest of them are just make it cleaner

**UPDATE**

Update your form Route

```
action="{{ route('deletepost',$post->id) }}"
```

To

```
action="{{ route('deletepost', ['id' => $post->id]) }}"
```

Comment: No it is not working. I found that when iam clicking on delete of first post the delete function in PostController is not called, but for every other post delete is working.